# How to get the node name of the parent node of an html element using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0

Well i need to get the parent node name and its respective attributes of an html element using c#.

**Example:**

```
<dl class="dlbox">
  <dd> 
      <a class="btn primary" href="http://testurl.org">
            <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
            <span class="icnsm"></span>     
      </a>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

**Code:**

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document; 
        HtmlElementCollection col = doc.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                int i = 0;

                foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
                {
            textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + col[i].GetAttribute("id") + "\r\n";
                i = i + 1;         
        }
```

**Note:** I am looping through the page and searching for all anchor tags, but i need to check the parent element at 2nd level i.e.  exists or not for  the respective anchor tag, if it exists then i need to get the class name for the respective dl using c#.

Thanks! Any help shall be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What code you wrote for this? You need to share the  code

Comment: I have added the code, could you please suggest on the same?

Answer (score 0):

well you could use `Parent` property, such as:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document; 
HtmlElementCollection col = doc.GetElementsByTagName("a");

int i = 0;

foreach (HtmlElement element in col)
{
    textBox8.Text = textBox8.Text + col[i].GetAttribute("id") + "\r\n";
    i = i + 1;

    // check if parent is dd
    if(element.Parent != null && element.Parent.TagName.ToLower() == "dd")
    {
        var parent = element.Parent;

        if(parent.Parent != null && element.Parent.TagName.ToLower() == "dl")
        {
            // get class name of dl
            var className = parent.Parent.GetAttribute("class");
        }
    }
}
```